# how to delete constraint when you don't remember constraint name

Tags: mysql

I've add a constraint on my table named cours a few days ago with mysql. the problem is that i want to delete the constraint and I don't remember the constraint's name I've used. When I want to delete the constraint they ask me to check if it exist

```
ALTER TABLE cours DROP FOREIGN KEY idEtudiant;
```

I expect my constraint to be removed but they say that is not exist

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just find out what constraints do you have there?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(constraint_name) 
FROM information_schema.table_constraints 
WHERE constraint_schema = DATABASE() AND table_name = 'cours' AND constraint_name <> 'PRIMARY'
ORDER BY constraint_name ASC;
```